# R - Multiple Columns on one single Scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Would you mind taking a look at this?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14vVWxhaQynPmnAsZHlrkkdeJTt0XlDzHc5JSd4DNF-Y/edit?usp=sharing

I have three variables; first one for Year from 2000 - 2017, second one for each country's GDP over the 2000-2017 and the third for soccer ranking over the 2000-2017.

I would like to draw one giant scatter plot; Year 2000-2017 on X-axis, Rank reversed starting from 200 on bottom to 1 on top on Y-axis while each scatter point size vary with GDP size.

All I can come up with is plotting a scatter plot for one country only:

> rank <- read.csv("Test1.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
>
> library(ggplot2)
>
> qplot(Year, Rank , data = rank, size = Aruba)

But I would like to fit all the countries into one scatter plot while y-axis being reversed and draw a linear regression of all scatter points if possible.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You need to reorganize your data to long form. Paste some reproducible data please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14vVWxhaQynPmnAsZHlrkkdeJTt0XlDzHc5JSd4DNF-Y/edit?usp=sharing Thanks guys!

Comment: It's definitely preferred if you can post a representative sample of data *in your question*, such as with `dput` or one of the packages suggested above, rather than linking folks to a third-party download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you want the regression done. But here is the graph.

**Edits:** Because there is a country named "Rankmibia" which I never heard of, select by prefix won't work, I used position this time.

```
rank <- read.csv("Test1.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)

library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

r=rank %>% select(seq(3,ncol(rank),2)) %>% gather(id,rank)
g=rank %>% select(1,seq(2,ncol(rank),2)) %>% gather(country,GDP,-Year)

df=cbind(g, rank=r$rank)
g=qplot(Year, rank , data = df, size = GDP, color=country)+scale_y_reverse()
ggsave("fig.png",g,width=40,height=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I tried your source code with the full data I have and keep getting 'Error in data.frame arguments implying differing number of rows with your source code.. Would you please help me with the case of full data as shown? : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14vVWxhaQynPmnAsZHlrkkdeJTt0XlDzHc5JSd4DNF-Y/edit#gid=485969225

Comment: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3366, 3402      # This error appears

Comment: Because there is a country named "Rankmibia" which I never heard of, messed up with prefix of "Rank". I have fixed the problem. Please see edited code.

Comment: I think it was meant to be Namibia but somehow it got merged with Rank :(